# Why won't my text center here?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
.me-header {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;
}

    .me-header a {
        color: #333;
        font: 10px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none
    }

.resume-header {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;

}

    .resume-header a {
        color: #333;
        font: 10px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none
    }

.center-text {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And the following HTML:

```
<div class="me-header">
                <a href="#"><img src="media/me-icon.png" alt="Picture of Christian Selig"><br> <span class="center-text">Contact Me</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="resume-header">
                <a href="resume.pdf"><img src="media/resume-icon.png" alt="Resume icon" title="Click to download resume (PDF)"><br> <span class="center-text">Resume (PDF)</span></a>
            </div>
```

But my text still comes out left-aligned. Why?

Comment: I assume it is picking up a style for another ID. Have you checked in firebug or something similar to see what styles are being applied?

Comment: Add `text-align:center;` to your me-header

Answer (score 4):

Both `a` and `span` are inline elements - so they are only as wide as their contents. So when you center the text, it is centred within the inline element, but the inline element appears on the left.

If you set `text-align: center;` on the parent block element it will work.

If you want to center the whole block, use an automatic margin.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
.center-text
{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Why would use you `display: table;` and not `display: block;`?

Comment: If you used `display: block;`, you wouldn't need to use margins, you'd just use `text-align: center;`. I just prefer `display: table;`, there's no other reason, really.

Comment: That makes no sense.  I would recommend you only use display: table; for specific situations.  Something as simple as centering a div, `display:block;` is the correct method.  He wants the div to behave as a block element, not a table.